# Would a user-wiped iPhone 11 still have 200k+ system files and database entries on it?

Tags: iphone, ios

Would a factory reset iPhone 11 Pro Max still have hundreds of thousands of files and database entries on it?

For clarity, when I say "factory reset," I mean a user-initiated reset via Settings > General > Reset > Erase All Content and Settings.

Comment: Get a clear answer from your client and maybe ask them to define forensic sanitation. The phone will come with files out of the factory many of which cannot be wiped, at least not without breaking the functionality of the phone.

Comment: Looking at the background here: isn‘t your question basically „how can I verify whether an iPhone got factory-reset“?

Comment: Re: "isn‘t your question...whether an iPhone got factory-reset," not really.  I've found some very authoritative publications summarizing several ways to do that and the goal of this question is limited to quantifying files and database entries present on an iPhone 11 post-"Erase All Content and Settings," which has been difficult due to Apple's reluctance to publish granular software/hardware detail.

Comment: That doesn’t make much sense - in what way would “Apple’s reluctance to publish” make that information hard to come by? You do not need secret hardware details to count files.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, when you choose "Erase All Content and Settings" it does not mean that the phone is literally wiped of all files and databases/settings. Rather it means that all user-related content and settings are erased.

You're still left with thousands of files for the operating system itself, built-in apps, and databases for settings (now set a default values) and so on.

Comment: Thanks.  If there's any way to quantify the amount of files/database entries on such a reset device (e.g., if >200k) or resources that may contain more granular detail in that regard I'd welcome any direction.  My thought was that the 6+ GB of firmware/OS that remains would comprise at least hundreds of thousands of files, although I am still looking for a authoritative citation for that proposition.

Comment: For example, I'd imagine the dictionary used for AutoCorrect/spell check alone could approach 100k files and/or database entries.

Comment: What is the practical purpose of this question?